# Binding BorderPane and Frame Height and Width

Tags: java, javafx, layout, binding, javafx-2

I am using JavaFX 2 in Netbeans. How do I get the width and height of an element to adjust when the Frame is resized? Here is my layout:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Hello World");
final Group root = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
border.setPrefWidth(stage.getWidth());
border.setPrefHeight(stage.getHeight());

HBox outerHBox = new HBox();
border.setCenter(outerHBox);
root.getChildren().add(border);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

**After some more research**
I found where this has been done before http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-stage-javafx-sdk but it is in an older FX (very different from JavaFX 2). I am having trouble translating it. Looks like I should be using binding? I've never used binding before and I've barely used FX.

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please simplify your example code? Maybe, just adding the `outerBox` to your `root` is sufficient.

Comment: @pmoule I simplified the example. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `Node` classes enable resizing. The `Group` class is one of these. You'll understand this when calling isResizable() on your `root` object. Use instead a subclass of `Region` e.g. `BorderPane` as your `root`.

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Hello World");

final BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(border);

Button button = new Button("test");

HBox outerHBox = new HBox();
outerHBox.getChildren().add(button);
outerHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

border.setCenter(outerHBox);

stage.setScene(scene);
```

Your example should work, now.

Comment: Thanks! :D I did find a way (with 2 dimension listeners on the stage) but this is much simpler.